# select records which have different values in the same column and different values in another column without subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this table:

```
item        year
----        ----
1           1999 
2           1999
3           1999 
2           2000 
4           2000 
2           2001
3           2001
4           2001
5           2001
```

And I need this result (with 1999 selected)

```
item        year
----        ----
4           2000
4           2001
5           2001
```

To sum up, I need to obtain new items which aren't in 1999, but which are defined in another different year (this is for adding them with another query later).

I'm using an old MySQL version and I'm **not able to use subqueries**. Is there any compatible solution?

Comment: try distinct key word http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL

Comment: Are the items continuous in their values, as in the example?

Comment: @Bohemian They aren't continuous necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this

```
SELECT t1.item, t1.year from table as t1
LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t2.item = t1.item AND t2.year = 1999
WHERE t2.item IS NULL
```

In "english" it means, select all the items from my table. Then for each item try to find if they are in the table with the year 1999, else put NULL.
Then you just have to say "keep the elements that do not have a matching element in t2.

Not sure if my explanation is better anyway

EDIT: you of course need to replace `table` with the name of your own table. I tested it on a small example and it seems to work.

EDIT2 : If you look at the result of the LEFT JOIN you would have something like this :

```
t1.item     t1.year    t2.item     t2.year
----        ----       ----        ----       
1           1999       1           1999
2           1999       2           1999
3           1999       3           1999
2           2000       2           1999
4           2000       NULL        NULL
2           2001       2           1999
3           2001       3           1999
4           2001       NULL        NULL
5           2001       NULL        NULL
```

Then if you add `WHERE t2.item IS NULL` you only keep the ones not having a year 1999 in the table.
Is it a better way to understand it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Because I think it works. You want to exclude every item that has a line in the table with the year 1999. That's the point of the LEFT JOIN : getthe ones in the table with the year 1999. Then the WHERE xxx IS NULL will only keep the ones not in the join.

Comment: Reading again your question and the answer by @bohemian you could add an `AND t1.year > 1999` if you only want the items after the year in question too.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.item, t2.year
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 
    on t2.year > t1.year 
    and t2.item != t1.item
where t1.year = 1999
and t2.item is null
```

Comment: your query is not selecting any record